# objective-c dictionary access as property/method

Tags: objective-c, reflection, dynamic, dictionary, properties

In my obj-c class, I have a dictionary mapping strings to objects.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
MyClass* obj = [[MyClass alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
```

Now, instead of doing:

```
NSString* val1 = [obj value:@"key1"];
```

I want to do:

```
NSString* val1 = [obj key1];  // @"value1"
NSString* val2 = [obj key2];  // @"value2"
NSString* val3 = [obj key3]; // nil, not found
```

Is it possible?

Of course this assumes that (a) dictionary keys are valid identifier names; and (b) there are no "real" properties/methods with the same name (this would probably call the real method instead).

Answer (score 5):

NSKeyValueCoding is an informal protocol that enables key value coding. It's part of Foundation, so it is already available to you.

You could try overriding `valueForUndefinedKey` which is called when you try to access something in a KVC way where there is no property or KVC compliant accessor. Then, in the overriden method, you could just pass the value of the key to the dictionary:

```
- (id) valueForUndefinedKey: (NSString*)aKey {
    return [obj objectForKey:aKey];
}
```

stick some error checking in there and you should be good to go.

Now when you call:

```
NSString *theKey = @"Key1";
NSString *val1 = [obj theKey];
```

and if there is no property called `Key1` and there is no method that returns an object called `Key1` it will call `valueForUndefinedKey:theKey` which will call into your dictionary for the object assigned to the key @"Key1".

Comment: Your answer is spot-on, though I'd be a bit concerned as to why the OP feels the need to do something like this. In general, it seems best to be cautious about introducing this kind of magic into a codebase if it doesn't give rise to some truly compelling benefit(s).

Comment: @jlehr: I'm looking for Javascript-like dictionary access. I do actually have a reason for it.

Comment: @Abizern: This is *almost* what I wanted. In your example above, I want to be able to call [obj Key1], not [obj @"Key1"].

Comment: @noamtm And the reason would be...?